# user-defined pre-commit hooks in svn?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I would like to set up a pre-commit hook to prevent incorrect commits, but I would like to define my own hook, without putting it in the svn repository. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: what do you mean "without putting it in the svn repository"? how would that work for other users?

Comment: @scibuff: that's the point. I don't want the hooks to work for other users. Only for me, and I don't want to access the svn repo.

Comment: ehhh, try to make a hook user specific, ie test for the username

Answer (score 0):

**Client-side** hooks exist **only** for TortoiseSVN (read SVN Book before asking questions)

You didn't mention your OS